# How to recover data from dying hard drive that constantly disconnects on linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, linux-mint, software-rec

I have an external USB hard drive that's in the process of dying.

I'm trying to use Linux Mint Cinnamon 20 to recover the files, just by cutting and pasting them. However, every ~30 seconds or so the drive will stop showing up, and the operation will fail. If I disconnect the cable and reconnect it the drive will show up once more and the operation will continue. This happens with known good cables.

Any suggestions for how best to get the data off this drive, without sitting there and disconnecting and reconnecting the cable every 30 seconds for 10 hours? I'm open to trying different distros, or performing a clone of the disk if either of these would work better.

[image: Bottom of the drive.]

[image: The connector on the drive.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112733/discussion-on-question-by-fangus-how-to-recover-data-from-dying-hard-drive-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously paid recovery services are the best option, they can replace the motor and any other failed components.

So it is going to take some experimentation but since paid recovery doesn't sound like an option try this.

Sounds like the hardware is failing you can't fix that your going to have to accept some amount of tedious into this process.  It could be the hard drives motor failing, in which case changing that is beyond 90% of peoples skill set.

You will need an output device larger than the source.

The only way to automate this is if you have an controlled outlet strip that you can periodically have a script turn OFF and ON with the hard drive on a separate power supply plugged into said outlet strip.

I am sure other brands of outlet strip might be able to do it, but I know for sure the kasa hs300 ($69.99 - $89.99 depending on the store and sale prices) has a python API on github (https://github.com/p-doyle/Python-KasaSmartPowerStrip) that can control there outlet strip from within linux.  I have done it, but not for this purpose.

So basically if you put the hard drive in an external usb chassis then an outlet strip could be used to automatically turn it OFF and ON to wake it up for 30 more seconds.  However, I don't know if your ready for this kind of complexity.

You could try ddrescue

```
ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sda test.img test.logfile
```

However, the hard drive will stop working every 30 seconds, and it will still have to be unplugged and re plugged every 30 seconds.

or

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=1000
```

Ok so now you have the first 1000 sectors.

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=1000 -skip=1000 seek=1000
```

So "skip" should skip the first 1000 sectors you already have.
"seek" advances the start position in the output file.

So now you just have to keep advancing the skip and seek values by the same factor as the count value.

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=1000 -skip=2000 seek=2000
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=1000 -skip=3000 seek=3000

dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=10000 -skip=4000 seek=4000
dd bs=512 if=/dev/sda of=/location/of/output/drv.img count=10000 -skip=14000 seek=14000
```

You can experiment with larger and larger count,skip,seek values to reduce the time it takes.

Basically you need to reach the maximum number of sectors you can read in 30 seconds (the fail time).  Then keep reading it in, in blocks of that size.

Eventually you will have your entire drive imaged.

then you can mount the image

```
mkdir /mnt/whatever
mount -o loop /blah.img /mnt/whatever
```

Then copying your files off is easy.

Comment: 1. Don't use `bs=512` as you'll end up doing multiple reads for each block of the device - as an absolute minimum use the physical disk block size. 2. `dd` will fail on a bad read - use `ddrescue` instead, which is designed to read failing disks

Comment: The risky part about this method is that the more one tries to recover data, the more the drive is used which adds stress which isn't the best to do with a drive that may be failing mechanically. Perhaps it's just the interface and not the drive and/or the data isn't all that important but in the case that one or both of those isn't true, continuing to use the drive can make things worse or make it so that the data can't be recovered at all no matter the method.

Comment: @NasirRiley  While I agree it isn't the best thing to do, the OP is here so the OP is clearly not going to pay hundreds of dollars for proper recovery.  So might as well attempt to help them with the only viable free method.

Comment: @cybernard That depends on how important the data is. There are people who come to this and other Stack Exchange sites to ask for help with physical servers at the company where they work even though it would be better to ask a colleague for help. My only suggestion is that the risks of attempting to recover data on one's own be included in any answers that are given. If the data really is that important and the OP isn't able or willing to pay money to have it recovered, then there's nothing more that can be done other than to have it be a lesson as to why backups are important.

Comment: Thanks! That ended up working (sort of).
I actually ended up using ddrescue normally, with a logfile to resume. The drive actually ended up disconnecting much less often than every thirty seconds, probably every 5 hours or so whilst creating the image. I presume this is because previously I was just copying and pasting the files I wanted, rather than using dedicated drive recovery software. Thank you very much for your assistance!